4G Hat for Raspberry Pi Zero trouble
I am currently trying to set up a 4G hat [SIM7600X 4G HAT(B)] for my Raspberry Pi 0, and I am following the guide found here:
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=224355
I have followed all the instructions carefully, but I have encountered an error that I cannot seem to resolve. When I enter the command sudo qmicli -p -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --device-open-net='net-raw-ip|net-no-qos-header' --wds-start-network="apn='ibox.tim.it',ip-type=4" --client-no-release-cid in the terminal, I receive the following error message:
https://imgur.com/XFplRXr
  lzer0:~>sudo qmicli -p -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --device-open-net='net-raw-ip|net-no-qos-header' --wds-start-network="apn='ibox.tim.it',ip-type=4" --client-no-release-cid error: couldn't open the QmiDevice: Transaction timed out lzer0:~>sudo qmicli -p -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --device-open-net='net-raw-ip|net-no-qos-header' --wds-start-network="apn='ibox.tim.it',ip-type=4" --client-no-release-cid error: couldn't start network: QMI protocol error (14): 'CallFailed' call end reason (3): generic-no-service verbose call end reason (3,2001): [cm] no-service [/dev/cdc-wdm0] Client ID not released:         Service: 'wds'             CID: '17'
I have tried searching for a solution to this error message, but I have not been successful. I was wondering if anyone in this community could help me out. I would greatly appreciate any advice or guidance you can provide.
I have attempted to connect using SIM cards from the Italian providers TIM and Wind, which offer data services, but encountered issues with both.
Interestingly, when they switched to a Vodafone SIM card that supports both data and voice calls, they were able to connect without any problems. This leads them to wonder if there is a distinct process for connecting data-only SIMs, such as those from TIM and Wind, compared to SIMs that support both data and voice calls, like the Vodafone SIM they used.
